# Anagram a specific word to describe a current event

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

Take a word, anagram it, add the original word to create a phrase.

I hope the answer is not too offensive during these trying times.

Bonus: Take the original word, anagram it again to describe the people's answer to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a word

> Pandemic

anagram it

> Damn epic

add the original word to create a phrase

> Damn epic pandemic

Take the original word, anagram it again to describe the people's answer to it.

> Camped In

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for

> CARNIVOROUS CORONAVIRUS?

I guess this is what you're getting at with "current event" and "trying times". Playing the pedant,

> a virus isn't technically carnivorous as it's not *eating* animals, but it's certainly killing animals.

Not sure about the bonus, but I suspect that's going to be more than one word.

Comment: Wow! That wasn't the anagram I had intended, but that is actually quite brilliant, regardless of fact. I lover the metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have something:

> Elvis lives

However, I don't understand what the bonus asks for.